# Significant change of direction, new question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Background: I was [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744707/python-scripts-not-working-outside-of-eclipse) about why I wasn't able to run a python script outside of Eclipse, and I found out that it was a strange syntax error, and not something wrong with my computer/python installation. Because of this, the problem is now quite a bit more specific than the general "script not working" question I originally asked.

Question: Should I create a whole new question (and link to it in my old question), or just completely reedit my current question (including title, body, tags, etc.) to reflect the change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question doesn't have any answer, yet, you could change it.
After all, you know why the code is not working, and answering to the currently asked question is rather difficult. As you are talking of a traceback, users could point there is something wrong in the code, but they would not be able to tell you what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Alright, thanks for clarifying that!